# Use 'try/except' instead of 'if' to find duplicates in a list

Tags: python

I'm making a program that finds item that are repeated in an array and I did have it working using the if command, but with long arrays the if command slows down the program so I wish to convent it to the try/except command.

Here's my code:

```
array = ['11', '5', '4', 'hello', '11', '7', 'a', '4']
seen = []
repeats = []

for item in array:
    if item not in seen:
        seen.append(item)
    else:
        repeats.append(item)

print(repeats)
```

Output:

[11, 4]

thanks

Comment: `try` is intended to be used when exceptional circumstances occur in your code. This usually means an error of some type. It should not be used as a normal sequence control. It certainly will not make your code faster than using an `if`.

Comment: Using exceptions for control flow is almost always a bad idea unless you can **really** (**really**) justify it. Make `seen` a set instead of a list to speed up membership lookup.

Comment: You need to do some better analysis to understand why your code is slow before trying to find a solution.

Comment: what causes you to believe that `if` is slow?   maybe it is `in` that is slow.

Comment: Python's exception-handling _is_ very efficient, and you may have read that `try ... except` code is faster than the equivalent `if ... else` code. However, that's only true when the exception isn't raised. Exception handling has considerable overheads when the exception is actually raised. Generally, if the exception happens more than 5-10% of the time using `try ... except` will be _slower_ than `if ... else` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a linear search in `seen` every time you insert, which grows computational time quadratically.

The easiest you can do is to use a dictionary key instead. Dictionaries can be looked up by key in an efficient way because they're internally hash maps.

```
array = ['11', '5', '4', 'hello', '11', '7', 'a', '4']
seen = {}
repeats = []

for item in array:
    if item not in seen:
        seen[item] = None
    else:
        repeats.append(item)

print(repeats)
```

As a commenter pointed out, the most pythonic way to do this in general is probably a `set` instead of a dict, because you don't need the dict's value - however I think it's worth knowing that both should give you the same performance:

```
array = ['11', '5', '4', 'hello', '11', '7', 'a', '4']
seen = set()
repeats = []

for item in array:
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
    else:
        repeats.append(item)

print(repeats)
```

Comment: FWIW, a set is essentially a dict with no values, and if you take a look at the CPython source code you will see many similarities between these objects. And while I agree that it's good to understand that you _can_ use a dict for this, it's even better to understand that a set is the correct object to use. Unless you're on a _really_ ancient version of Python without set support (but then you deserve all the trouble you get). ;)

Comment: BTW, your set version has a typo: `set.add(item)` should be `seen.add(item)`. Or get rid of the `else` block & don't worry about adding repeated elements to `seen`. Eg, `if item in seen: repeats.append(item)` followed by `seen.add(item)` outside the `if` block.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. The reason why I put the dict first was because it is a more powerful concept than set. Since I think OP is quite new to python, IMO it's best to learn about dictionaries first, even if it's not the most pythonic for a specific usecase. That's also why I wouldn't even go into standard libraries that can be used for this - first one has to understand the basics because (s)he should go into the libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I think I will leave OPs code intact otherwise, just to keep it clear that no other amendment is necessary to get it working.

Comment: I get what you mean: dict is vital to how Python works, set is a relatively recent addition. And one should certainly understand the built-in types before investigating the fancier versions in the standard libraries, like defaultdict and Counter. IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Try/Except is not meant for this problem.

Just use the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from the collections module.

```
from collections import Counter
array = ['11', '5', '4', 'hello', '11', '7', 'a', '4']

repeats = [key for key,value in Counter(array).items() if value>1]

print (repeats) #will print ['11','4']
```

You can use [Michel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41477661/3225001) if you do not want to use Counter class.

I tested for performance, and here are the results:

```
For n=10^3
Using Counter:          0.0011416s
Using sets and if-else: 0.0006266s

For n=5*10^3
Using Counter:          0.0024912s
Using sets and if-else: 0.0027905s

For n=10^5
Using Counter:          0.0041075s
Using sets and if-else: 0.0054351s

For n=10^6
Using Counter:          0.0333123s
Using sets and if-else: 0.0513704s
```

**Update**: 
This might not be relevant to OP's question, but adding this for future viewers.

I tested again based on the uniqueness of the elements. I'd have to say that using sets and if-else is way better than Counter for lists having size n < 10^4.

For sizes greater than 10^5 Counter only outperforms by a mere margin of ~0.01s in the case of 50% redundancy. But, if redundancy is about 70-80%, then Counter is better by ~0.02s (again, n is of the order 10^5 or greater).
Percentage of uniqueness = `len(set(my_list))/len(my_list)`.

Comment: Interesting measurements. I would have guessed sets are always faster. But I guess the branching in script is what's costing performance, while Counter has some fixed overhead?

Edit: By that I mean n branches, rather than only k branches if k is the number of unique entries in the list? Maybe it would be interesting to measure how the benchmark behaves if the list is completely unique, my guess is the performance is either the same or better for sets again.

Comment: Yes, I think so too that the branching is costing the performance. But, not sure if Counter has a fixed overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the update and your effort with benchmarking. This confirms my intuition.

Answer (score -1):

You can also write a very nice implementation of this using python's built-in `Counter` which will give you counts for each value very efficiently and has nice semantics for doing counter subtractions.

```
from collections import Counter
a = Counter(array)
# a == Counter({'11': 2, '4': 2, 'a': 1, '5': 1, '7': 1, 'hello': 1})
seen = a.keys()
# seen = ['11', 'a', '5', '4', '7', 'hello'] 
b = Counter(a.keys())
# b == Counter({'11': 1, 'a': 1, '5': 1, '4': 1, '7': 1, 'hello': 1})
# here is the neat trick because Counter subtraction will remove
# any keys that end up with count 0
repeat = (a - b)
# repeat == Counter({'11': 1, '4': 1})
remaining = repeat.keys()
# [ '11', '4' ]
```

Comment: Please explain why your code solves the OP's problem.

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.